# LZ4 Compression (C++) and Decompression (Java)

Tags: java, compression, lz4

My objective is to compress a file using LZ4 in C++ and to decompress it in Java.

My text file (A.txt):

```
Hi, Hello everyone.
Thanks.
```

The file after c++ compression (A.txt.lz4):

```
"M@Pw  €Hi, Hello everyone.
Thanks.
```

Then I decompressed it in Java (B.txt):

```
i, Hello everyone.
Thanks.
```

The problem is I'm not getting the first character of every file. I can't figure out where I'm going wrong.

My java code:

```
public static void uncompressLz4File(String str1, String str2) {
File f1 = new File(str1);
File f2 = new File(str2);
try (InputStream fin = Files.newInputStream(f1.toPath());
        BufferedInputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(fin);
        OutputStream out = Files.newOutputStream(Paths.get(f2.getAbsolutePath()));
        FramedLZ4CompressorInputStream zIn = new FramedLZ4CompressorInputStream(in))
{
    int n;
    zIn.getCompressedCount();
    byte[] b = new byte[1];
    int uncompressedLength = zIn.read(b, 0, 1) == -1 ? -1 : b[0] & 255;
    b[0] = (byte) uncompressedLength;
    final byte[] buffer = new byte[uncompressedLength];
    while (-1 != (n = zIn.read(buffer)))
    {
        out.write(buffer);
    }
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    
}
}

public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException
{
    String str1 = "C:\\Users\\aravinth\\Desktop\\A.txt.lz4";
    String str2 = "C:\\Users\\aravinth\\Desktop\\B.txt";
    uncompressLz4File(str1, str2);  
}
```

Any help would be useful. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

There is a [factory](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-compress/apidocs/org/apache/commons/compress/compressors/CompressorStreamFactory.html) for creating streams that should take care of the check:

```java
CompressorInputStream zIn =
    new CompressorStreamFactory()
    .createCompressorInputStream(CompressorStreamFactory.LZ4_BLOCK, in);
```

or `LZ4_FRAMED` depending on what the C++ library generates.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone for the help. I fixed it using this code.

```
public static void uncompressLz4File(String str1, String str2) {
    File f1 = new File(str1);
    File f2 = new File(str2);
    try (FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(f1);
            BufferedInputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(fin);
            OutputStream out = Files.newOutputStream(Paths.get(f2.getAbsolutePath()));
            FramedLZ4CompressorInputStream zIn = new FramedLZ4CompressorInputStream(in)) {
        int n;
        byte[] b = new byte[1024];
        while ((n = zIn.read(b)) > 0) {
            out.write(b, 0, n);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```